# Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a local ring. Then $\mathrm{soc}(M) = \{ r \in M \mid \mathfrak mr = 0 \}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Given that $(R,\mathfrak m)$ is a local ring we want to show that 
>   $\mathrm{soc}(M) = \{ r \in M \mid \mathfrak mr = 0 \}$, where $M$ is an $R$-module.

I tried the following. Let N be an essential module of R. then I tried showing that $ soc(M) \subset N$
But I was unable to do this. any ideas?
thanks in advance

Comment: It is the definition of  $soc$ in B-H. what definition of $Soc$ do you use?

Comment: Soc(M) is the intersection of essential modules of M. Or equivalently the sum of simple modules of M.

Comment: Any simple module is isomorphic to $R/M$ ,where $M$ is a maxiaml ideal of $R$. So if $R$ is  a local ring, then any simple module is of the form $R/ \mathfrak m$